# How to Independently run positional and continuous servos using millis()?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, millis, delay

I am setting up 3 servos (**2 position servos and 1 '360' continuous rotational servo**) with Arduino. but I failed to run these independently. It runs one after another. I wish to run it in loop independent to each other. Here is the code which I use to run positional servo and CR (360) servo. default servo positions are 90.
*CR 360 servo should be running independently 90-60-120-90 (in loop)
*Pos servo should be running one after another (in loop)

**To run positional servos (tilt/pan):**

```
//tilt servo
    for (pos = 90; pos >= 60; pos -= 1)     //90 ~ 60
  {
    tiltservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }

  for (pos = 60; pos <= 120; pos += 1)      //60 ~ 120
  {
    tiltservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }

  for (pos = 120; pos >= 90; pos -= 1)       //120 ~ 90
  {
    tiltservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }

//pan servo
for (pos = 90; pos >= 60; pos -= 1)          //90 ~ 60
  {        
    panservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }

  for (pos = 60; pos <= 120; pos += 1)       //60 ~ 120
  {        
    panservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }

  for (pos = 120; pos >= 90; pos -= 1)       //120 ~ 90
  {        
    panservo.write(pos);
    delay(30);
  }
```

**To run CR 360 servo:**

```
 legservo.writeMicroseconds(1600);      //CW
 delay(5000);                           //run for 5s
 legservo.writeMicroseconds(1300);      //CCW
 delay(5000);                           //run for 5s
```

Tried this to independently run CR servos, but how to put some wait (3s-4s) in between FW and RW.

```
if (millisNow - lastMillis >= 10000) 
{ 
lastMillis = millisNow; 
if (crservoState == 0) 
 { 
   legservo1.writeMicroseconds(2150); //FW
   crservoState = 1; 
 } 
  else 
 { 
   legservo1.writeMicroseconds(850);  //RW
   crservoState = 0; 
 } 
}
```

**Trial code after suggestions:**

```
uint32_t milliSNow = millis();

  if (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate >= 1000)
  {
    if (crservoState == 0)
    {
      if (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate >= 10000)
      {
        legservo1.writeMicroseconds(2150);    //FW run
        crservoState = 2;
        lastTimeServoRotate = milliSNow;
      }
    }

    if (crservoState == 1)
    {
      if (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate >= 10000)
      {
        legservo1.writeMicroseconds(850);     //RW run
        crservoState = 3;
        lastTimeServoRotate = milliSNow;
      }
    }

    if (crservoState == 2)
    {
      if (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate >= 3000)
      {
        legservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);    //FW STOP
        crservoState = 1;
        lastTimeServoRotate = milliSNow;
      }
    }

    if (crservoState == 3)
    {
      if (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate >= 3000)
      {
        legservo1.writeMicroseconds(1500);     //RW STOP
        crservoState = 0;
        lastTimeServoRotate = milliSNow;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/83977/how-to-run-2-different-servo-continuous-rotation-and-regular-servo-in-parallel/83984#83984

Comment: @ArduinoFan thanks for sharing the link, I tried this but this is for controlling same type of servos, in my case i need to set up positional servo and CR as well, so its getting mixed operation. while running pan/tilt one after another with continuously running CR servo CW/CCW with wait time of 2s. any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The last code snippet you posted should work, albeit with 10 second (rather than 3–4 s) pauses between FW and RW. If it doesn't work, you have an issue elsewhere in your code. Maybe you are sharing the `lastMillis` variable with the code handling the positional servos?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for your comment. This code works to run CR in this manner..
1. when start, it run after 10s    

2. servo1 run for 10s FW then immediately run for 10s RW in loop. but I wish to hold/wait for 3s after 10s FW and 10s RW run each.    

3. 'lastMillis' is only used for CR servo, its not clashing with POS servo variable.

Comment: Re “_I wish to hold/wait for 3s after 10s FW and 10s RW run each_”: This is not in your code snippet. If you want these pauses, you have to explicitly ask the servo to stop, and your cycle has **four** phases: FW, pause, RW, pause.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thank you. I uploaded it as 'Trial code', Could you please check it?
since its working but the fw/rw run time is 3s instead of 10s and holding time is 10s instead of 3s though i defined it to run for 10s and hold/stop for 3s. where I am mistaking? please suggest~

Comment: @EdgarBonet I just flipped (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate) check from 10000 to 3000 and it run. (milliSNow - lastTimeServoRotate), this checks the time elapsed time. 
But when start, it wait for 10s to run, even I set it to check with >= 1000 (~1s), I didn't get it. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial.
Let me paraphrase the main part of the example code here:

```cpp
uint8_t ledState = LOW;
uint32_t lastTimeLedChanged = 0;

void loop() {
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - lastTimeLedChanged >= 1000) {

        // Save the last time we updated the LED.
        lastTimeLedChanged = now;

        // Compute the new state of the LED.
        if (ledState == LOW) {
            ledState = HIGH;
        } else {  // ledState is HIGH
            ledState = LOW;
        }

        // Set the LED to the computed state.
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledState);
    }
}
```

This will make the LED cycle between its two possible states at the
desired rate. You can apply this principle as-is to your continuous
rotation servo.

For the positional servos, the same principle can still be applied, but
there is a catch. Whereas both the LED and the CR servo cycle between
two states, the pair of positional servos goes through many states
(<s>92</s> 240 if I counted correctly). You will thus need:

- more variables to store the current state of the servo pair
- more code to compute the new desired state
- more code to update the state

In order to figure out how to represent the state, you have to look at
your current `delay()`-based code, see how many calls to `delay()` are
performed on each full cycle, and figure out how to identify each of
these calls. Each of these delays corresponds to one state of your
system. I would say that you need one variable to know in which of the
`for` loops you are, and another variable to know the last position you
wrote to the servo in that loop. I will call each of the original `for`
loops a “phase”. There are <s>two</s> six such phases:

- phase 0: tilt: 90° → 60°
- phase 1: tilt: 60° → 120°
- phase 2: tilt: 120° → 90°
- phase 3: pan: 90° → 60°
- phase 4: pan: 60° → 120°
- phase 5: pan: 120° → 90°

**Note** there were only two `for` loops in the original question, but
it was then edited to include six loops, thus I edited my answer.

An then you will need to store the time of the last update, thus:

```cpp
int phase = 0;  // which of the six phases we are in
int pos = 90;   // last position written to a servo
uint32_t lastTimeServoMoved = 0;
```

Once you have the proper variables to describe the state, updating it is
not hard. If you have reached the end of a phase, move to the next one.
Then update the position by one step. Thus:

```cpp
void loop() {
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - lastTimeServoMoved >= 30) {

        // Save the last time we updated a positional servo.
        lastTimeServoMoved = now;

        // Compute the new state.        
        if (phase == 0 && pos == 60)
            phase = 1;
        else if (phase == 1 && pos == 120)
            phase = 2;
        else if (phase == 2 && pos == 90)
            phase = 3;
        else if (phase == 3 && pos == 60)
            phase = 4;
        else if (phase == 4 && pos == 120)
            phase = 5;
        else if (phase == 5 && pos == 90)
            phase = 0;
        if (phase == 1 || phase == 4)
            pos += 1;
        else
            pos -= 1;

        // Set the servo to the computed state.
        if (phase < 3)
            tiltservo.write(pos);
        else
            panservo.write(pos);
    }
}
```

I personally do not like this kind of repetitive code. If you are
comfortable with data structures, I would recommend using an array of
structs to store all the information describing the moves that are done
in each phase:

```cpp
struct {
    Servo *servo;   // which servo to move
    int step;       // steps by which it moves
    int final_pos;  // final angular position
} moves[] = {
    { &tiltservo, -1, 60 },   // tilt:  90 ->  60
    { &tiltservo, +1, 120 },  // tilt:  60 -> 120
    { &tiltservo, -1, 90 },   // tilt: 120 ->  90
    { &panservo,  -1, 60 },   // pan:   90 ->  60
    { &panservo,  +1, 120 },  // pan:   60 -> 120
    { &panservo,  -1, 90 }    // pan:  120 ->  90
};
```

Then the actual code becomes simpler:

```cpp
void loop() {
    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - lastTimeServoMoved >= 30) {

        // Save the last time we updated a positional servo.
        lastTimeServoMoved = now;

        // Compute the new state.
        if (pos == moves[phase].final_pos) {
            phase +=1;
            if (phase == 6)
                phase = 0;
        }
        pos += moves[phase].step;

        // Set the servo to the computed state.
        moves[phase].servo->write(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation with example. Its good to understand. I tried this but CR servo doesn't wait for 5s between CW and CCW move.

The actual operation should be:

` CR servo:  (in loop)

running CW for 5s, 

wait for 2s, 

CCW for 5s `


` Pos (pan/tilt) servo:  (in loop)

1st pan move from 90~60, 60~120, 120~90 then

2nd tilt move from 90~60, 60~120, 120~90 `

Please suggest.

Comment: @Emlinux: This doesn't seem to match the code in your question. Please, update the question with the relevant information. Try to be as clear as possible, in order to avoid more misunderstandings of your requirements.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I updated it accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating the solution. I understood it. Though I didn't use data structure much, but its good to use it here efficiently. I will prefer to learn and use it like this. 
since there is 1 more leg_servo (CR 360) included, I tried to add that in loop with position servos like this. but I am unable to pause that for 2~3 seconds after CW/CCW run for 10s.

 if (millisNow - lastMillis >= 10000)  { lastMillis = millisNow;
    if (crservoState == 0) { legservo1.writeMicroseconds(2150);
      crservoState = 1; } else { legservo1.writeMicroseconds(850);   crservoState = 0; } }

Comment: Please suggest some. Thanks.

Comment: @Emlinux: Please, try to understand the _general approach_ illustrated by this answer: breaking down the cycle into phases, identifying the individual steps within each phase, figuring out how to encode and update the state... Although the code I show is specific to the tilt and pan servos, the approach is generic and, if you understand it, you can apply it to the CR servo. **Do not rush into writing code**: do the thinking and analysis first.

Comment: yes @Edgar Bonet, I tried the same so I shared few lines of code in my previous post. since I need to run the CR servos independent to POS servos (pan/tilt), I tried to run it independently for 10s FW and 10s RW and it runs but I am not sure how to put some wait_delay (like 3s) between FW and RW. Thanks.

Comment: since its not well visible the code mentioned in my previous comments, i put it in the end of the post. please check and guide. Thanks.